# Вопрос по работе Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var best = a.GroupBy(n => n)
                .Select(g => (count: g.Count(), value: g.Key))
                .Max();
```

Как Max() понимает что нужно находить максимальное именно к Count, а не к Value?
Какой механизм работы?

Comment: `(count: g.Count(), value: g.Key)` - это кортеж, кортежи сравниваются лексикографически, сначала находится Max для первого элемента, если находятся несколько одинаковых Max, то проверяется второй элемент среди них.